# Garbled words for cv2.imshow():

Tags: python, opencv

I use:

```py
cv2.imshow('Video', frame)
```

However, it displayed:

[image]

The detailed code:

```
# Display the results
    for (top, right, bottom, left), name in zip(face_locations, face_names):
        # Scale back up face locations since the frame we detected in was scaled to 1/4 size
        top *= 4
        right *= 4
        bottom *= 4
        left *= 4

        # Draw a box around the face
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), 2)

        # Draw a label with a name below the face
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, bottom - 35), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
        cv2.putText(frame, name, (left + 6, bottom - 6), font, 1.0, (255, 255, 255), 1)

    # Display the resulting image
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

    # Hit 'q' on the keyboard to quit!
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# Release handle to the webcam
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I suspect it has something to do with the computer, because it can display normally on a different computer.I want to know why it happens and how to solve the problem.

Comment: How did you install opencv?

Comment: Can you post an example of your code that is resulting in an error?

Comment: similar effects can occur when you corrupt the heap by mixing debug and release build of vc runtime library. Not sure whether this can happen in python.

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with the computer, because it can display normally on a different computer.